# Epicor documentation on Erp, Erp.UI, Ice.Lib, and other higher level namespaces

Tags: c#, customization, epicorerp, epicor

Does anyone know if there is documentation available in Epicor on what methods/properties are accessible in the "higher level" namespaces like Erp, Erp.UI, Erp.UI.App, Ice.Lib, etc? 
[For Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxK2W.png)

I know we have the object explorer which is incredibly useful in most cases, but it does not appear to show anything beyond UI objects, Adapters, and EpiDataViews. [UI objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw56u.png) [Data Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucaXp.png) [Adapters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTOSe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question to the EpiUsers forums as well (https://www.epiusers.help/t/erp-ui-app-namespace-documentation/64503) and it turns out this isn't officially documented anywhere. However, you can still get this information by de-compiling.